# Getting a paragraph value in MigraDoc

Tags: c#, migradoc

I've got a line here :

```
Paragraph par = row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Value");
```

Is there a way to get the text value from par? I have tried par.GetValue() but that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paragraphs can contain a mix of text with different sizes, fonts, attributes along with images and other things.

Here's a code snippet that gets the first text element:

```
if (para.Elements.Count > 0)
{
    Text t = para.Elements[0] as Text;
    if (t != null)
    {
        string s = t.Content;
        ...
    }
}
```

You know what your code adds to the paragraph, so you should know what you have to extract.

I do not know what you are trying to do. Every MigraDoc document object has a Tag member for custom use. You can assign any object (including `string`) to this Tag.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I do not know about the Tag, never seen it before